# Implement asynchronous thread (Xcode using Swift)

Tags: swift, asynchronous, sprite-kit

I have created a game in Xcode that currently is implemented heavily using the `update` function within SpriteKit. It looks something like this:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if(gameStatus == status.preGame){

        //function calls here

    }

    else if(gameStatus == status.startUp){

        //function calls here
    }

    else if(gameStatus == status.inGame){

        //heavy function calls here

    }
}
```

When it is in game, there are multiple calls in order to randomly create nodes and move them and such. I ran across Async threads, and I searched the internet to try and figure out how to implement them, but I could not find anything that helped me with what I am looking for.

I have ran into some lag issues because of how I currently have it implemented, and I was told that Async would potentially help solve this issue a little. I was wondering if anyone knew how to implement it for my structure.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I do not  think your issue is async actions,  I think your issue is bad design.  Async actions should only be used when you need to do work over a period of time that would end up blocking the main thread from completing its update cycle.  In your case, you have a constant amount of heavy action going on every frame, so that is all going to keep building and building and your game will not by in sync

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for your response. Is there anyway to do what I'm looking for in order to keep it in sync and not build up?

Comment: We need to know what is causing the slow down

Answer (score 0):

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    if(gameStatus == status.preGame){

        //function calls here

    }

    else if(gameStatus == status.startUp){

        //function calls here
    }

    else if(gameStatus == status.inGame){

        //heavy function calls here

    }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can I put this right within the update function under the given game state? I am also a little confused between which section handles what part of my function calls

Comment: yes you can write this in your update function just call your if else statement in background queue and on main thread if any UI updates required else you can also leave it blank. using this You will be able to call your update in backGround and in main thread your user will see its result (Maybe no lags). but use it in well way don't update any UI or reload Anything in background

Comment: My game crashes whenever it hits the async thread... confusing

Comment: check now please

Comment: I am enumerating multiple nodes in order to move them on the screen. My game always crashes after one of those enumerations, but it seems to be random where it crashes.. this didn't happen before, just when I added the async

Comment: please check the bottom of my question for how I implemented it to see if i did it correctly. Thank you btw!

Comment: just run backGround queue once it will call the function in back queue not differently for all if else

Comment: Unfortunately it still crashes where I am enumerating nodes... frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this will only help if you're blocking the operation on the main thread. You also need to be careful your operations don't get fired more often than they get completed, etc.

An operation queue can help with this, and clearly you only need to resort to async where "heavy loads" are (as needless complexity during startup may not be required

```
lazy var updateQueue:OperationQueue = {
    var queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "Update Game"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    return queue
}()

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    switch gameStatus {
    case .preGame:
        //function calls here
        break
    case .startUp:
        //function calls here
        break
    case .inGame:
        self.updateQueue.addOperation(){
            //heavy function calls here
            print("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It defines a queue for the operations to run in, it's similar in that it will run "somewhere else" - but in this case you create NSOperation to encapsulate the block/code being called.

Comment: Also, it can help during debugging that threads running on a queue have the name of that queue.

Comment: My game terminates right at the end of the self.updateQueue...(){ } call. I only put one function within the brackets

Comment: I'll fire it up

Comment: Not sure what is happening with you - updated answer for Swift 3.0. It sounds like you either have threading issues or access violations happening. Can you please provide some insights into what "terminate" or "crash" is?

Comment: In theory, you should be able to perform your operations on the main update loop in 99% of cases. I doubt your operations would exceed the capacity. Can you please tell me what the lag is? I suggest profiling

Comment: Can you please run your original code without async/queue and run the timer profiler under instruments with Xcode?

Comment: The lag is just slow frames. It starts at 60FPS and then shoots down to 30FPS. I know it is from the functions calls because I did previously run it with the profile and that where I found that out

Comment: ERROR: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: I'm suspicious the lag isn't due to your operations but the actual objects on scene. I.e. if you're doing too many animations or rendering of frames, it may not matter where it's threaded, using the sprite kit api, it handles the processing for you - does this make sense?

Comment: To give you insight into what is going on, objects are created that fall from the top, come up from the bottom, and move in from the right. Its a scrolling background, and all the objects that are created are enumerated to change the nodes position += to the game speed so they are also scrolling with the background. The nodes on screen rarely reach 50.. usually between 40-45

Comment: I really appreciate your help, by the way!

Comment: Would that fall under too much rendering? When you say SpriteKit does the processing for me, what do you mean exactly? Am I doing something that is already handled? All my nodes are saved to textures, also.

Comment: Do they all have physics bodies? What type of operations are you running?

Comment: I mean that if you perform an SKAnimation or add a body, Sprite will queue the processing of this and balance it with UI updates

Comment: Yes, they have physics bodies where as they are enemy objects to the player. The ones from the top fall by gravity to the bottom, when contacted with the ground create fire sparks for about 1 second. The ones from the right just move across the screen to the left. And the ones on the bottom run a sequence to basically go less than a 1/4th up the screen and back down. All the nodes are deleted once they leave the screen.

Comment: In runs almost flawless on my test device (iPhone 6s), but lags as I said before going down to 30FPS on test flight devices from my family members (iPhone 7s)

Comment: I also tried the test flight version on my phone with no problems as well

Comment: I would suggest the timer profiler here. It could be too much physics processing. Timer profile will tell you how much CPU and where it is being spent.

Comment: Ok and say it is too much physics processing... is there any way around that besides lessening the work load?

Comment: reducing the granularity or precision, (or taking smaller steps in world time).